# delete passing variable in a query using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem when I want to delete a record from query which uses
a bound variable. It worked before I moved to PDO.

```
<?php
require_once "konversi.php";

$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db_personalia="personalia";

try{
$id_mysql=new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db_personalia",$user,$password);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage("MySQL Error");
}

//Get code passed by user
$kode = $_GET['kode'];
if (empty($kode))
die("Invalid");

//convert value
$kode = turn_text($kode);

//value in variable
$kode=$_GET['kode'];

try{
$sql=$id_mysql->prepare("delete from member where nip =:kode");
$sql->bindValue(':kode',$kode);
$sql->execute();
}catch (PDOException $e)
{
print ("The statement failed.\n");
print ("getCode: ". $e->getCode (). "\n");
print ("getMessage: ".$e->getMessage (). "\n");
}

$id_mysql=null;
?>
```

Comment: @EatPeanutButter `new PDO` come on...

Comment: Any concrete error message you want to tell us about? Or perhaps the table structure, contents and `$kode` value.

Answer (score 1):

There is something that I don't really understand what you are trying to do.
This part:

```
$kode = $_GET['kode'];
if (empty($kode))
die("Invalid");
//convert value
$kode = turn_text($kode);

//value in variable
$kode=$_GET['kode'];
```

So let me guess what could be wrong here:

1. The $_GET['kode'] is undefined and in your SQL, you declared NOT NULL on that column. Also the empty() method is for an array. Instead, use isset() method.
2. I don't know what the method turn_text() does in your code, but its useless if you OVERRIDE the var $kode in your next line :)